# Run a .command file after giving permissions on macOS in Java

Tags: java, macos, terminal, runtime, desktop

I am trying to generate and execute a .command file in my Java program in macOS.

The program successfully generates the file, but it's the executing that's the issue.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod a+x \"" + U.base + File.separator + "/Game/run.command\"");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(U.base, "Game/run.command"));
```

When this is run, it still gives me the popup dialog:

> The file "run.command" could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges.

However, when I run the command "chmod a+x filepath" separately in terminal manually, the program is able to execute the file. I assume this is an issue with my usage of "Runtime.getRuntime().exec()"

Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the `chmod` command through the Runtime, it apparently takes the quotes (\") as a part of the path. When I removed the quotes from the ends, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set `chmod 755` as well.

`chmod a+x` will add the exec bits to the file but will not touch other bits. For example file might be still unreadable to `others` and `group`.

`chmod 755` will always make the file with perms 755 no matter what initial permissions were.

If it still doesnt work, it would be good to have an Exception to analyze.

Comment: Okay, so I outputted the results of the Runtime process, and it said no such file or directory. When I took away the quotes from the ends (\") it worked! However, now that I removed the quotes, how do I allow for folders that may have spaces in them?

For example when the path is this:
`/Users/dilan/Documents/DMSUpdater/DMS_V-B/Game/test boi/runMC.command`


It says this:
`chmod: /Users/dilan/Documents/DMSUpdater/DMS_V-B/Game/test: No such file or directory
chmod: boi/runMC.command: No such file or directory`

Comment: If you have a folder or file with a space, you need to preceed the space with a backslsh `\'. For example "/Users/dilan/Documents/DMSUpdater/DMS_V-B/Game/test\\ boi/runMC.command". Please accept the previous answer, thanks.